# What is the best type of rating for a casino game?

Tags: ratings, rating-system

We are looking to implement a rating system for our casino games for our users. The rationale being that the more popular a game is with users, the more others will play it, thus encouraging them to choose a game quicker and encourage play the more popular games and increasing the conversion for us.

We need the user playing a game as quickly and as effortlessly as possible, the quicker a user chooses, the faster the conversion happens.

We have narrowed it down to 2 options:

1. Like/heart with a total number of likes next to it. Gives a numerical total as to how many people like the game next to the heart icon.
2. Star ratings. A user is able to rate a game out of 5 stars.

The question is what is the best rating system to implement? Are there any criticisms of each system?

Comment: Thanks guys that what I search :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casino players likes a kind of objective information instead of subjective opinion. This could be number of games played, total bet or win value, etc. This could be represented not in absolute numeric values but in a kind of relative rating like a number of app installations in application stores, e.g. *100+ thousand spins!* or so.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered trying A/B testing of the two options? Seems like if you just have these two as candidates, A/B testing should show you which of them is the most successful.

Comment: I have, but right now we dont have the capability at this point in time, a couple of weeks maybe. So for now we are exploring the ideas

Comment: Got it. Of your two options, it seems to me that the star rating is the most ubiquitous for games (I'm thinking mostly of app stores). It also seems the most useful in that users could choose to filter/sort by that (e.g. at least 3 stars).If you go this route, I would also include the number of votes the app has received.

Comment: One of the cons we have with this system which a few of us seem to be getting stuck at is, it seems very subjective, one mans junk and all that. Where as a like shows how many players like it and play it. BUT its not really qualitative to the user.

Comment: Yeah I get that, I just think that star ratings (along with numeric ratings like X out of Y, or Z%) are so common historically as rating systems that users will likely understand what they mean. 

Likes seems to be less easy to parse - if 100 people "like" a game, is that good if 10,000 actually played it?

Comment: I think it stems from social media and how likes work there, this is where that idea came from. We dont want the most profitable games ranked at 1 star, but we can affect how many likes it receives by giving it more priority in the UI

Comment: So it sounds like you are heading down the "like" route! If you don't want the possibility of low scores, that makes sense. I guess you could also introduce the concept of trending games (games most frequently played in past hour/day/week etc). And you could also create some kind of "featured game" aspect if you really wanted to bump up the visibility of a specific game without it necessarily having many likes.

Comment: Admittedly it is my preference, but some in the team prefer stars. We actually have those types of things in place already which is useful for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to use icons to represent the rating of a certain game then stars is always the safe option as it's universally understood - even in different locales around the globe.

You could even play on the fact you are a casino by using relative icons in place of the standard stars, for example:

- Poker chips
- Dollar/pound/euro sign
- Coins/notes

Alternatively you may want to display the amount of times a particular game has been played so below the modal for the game you could have *played 1000 times in the past 7 days* or *70% win rate in the past 24 hours*. Play on the fact people want to win!

On a side note I'm not fond of gambling rules/laws so all wording etc would need to conform.